# Subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I know this is a very simple question.

I am studying introduction to linear algebra by gilbert strang. But i cannot seem to understand this worked example.

> Describe a subspace $S$ of each vector space $V$, and then a subspace $SS$ of $S$:
>   $V_1 =$ all combinations of $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$
>
> Answer:
>       $V_1$ starts with three vectors. A subspace comes from all combinations of the first two vectors $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,0)$. A subspace $SS$ of $S$ comes from all multiples $(c,c,0,0)$ of the first vector. So many possibilities.

2 questions:

Firstly, why is the subspace not $\mathbb{R}^4$(combination of all the vectors)? Since all would be able to pass through the origin.

What does it exactly mean by subspace of a subspace?

Comment: To be a bit picky, answer is wrong because $V_1$ is a subspace of $V_1$. Subspace of a subspace is just a subspace of subspace when latter subspace is considered as (independent) vector space on its own right

Comment: @user160738 Sorry but i still do not understand the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^4$ can't be a subspace of $V_1$ because the vector $(1,0,0,0)$ is not in $V_1$ (i.e. it's not a linear combination of $(1,1,0,0)$, $(1,1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$).

In general you can't span $\mathbb{R}^n$ with less than $n$ vectors.

Comment: Thanks. But why is it the first 2 vectors but not the first 3?

Comment: If I'm not missunderstanding the task is to define _some_ subspace of $V_1$, so you can chose the span of the first two vectors, or the span of all of them (in that case the subspace is $V_1$ itself) or the span of any vector in $V_1$, there are infinite amount of subspaces...

Comment: Yes, but why is the span of 2 vectors instead of 3?

Comment: Because he decided to describe the subspace generated by two vectors instead of the subspace which is the space itself. That's just a decision, both cases are valid answers but he've chosen that case among an infinite amount of posibilities. If the question is "why did he make that decision?", then the answer is not mathematical but psychological